# Showing that a Polynomial is Irreducible Over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

What is the most "efficient" way of showing that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$? In particular, how do I show $p(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 2$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$? The only way I can think of is the brute force method, and there has to be a smarter solution, right? Thank you.

Comment: Well, *efficient* and *elegant* in my mind have two very different meanings. For example, it is extremely efficient to just try all elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to see whether any of those are roots, which is what I assume you intended as the "brute force method".

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess I should've been clearer. I meant if there is a "smarter" way than just simply trying all elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (so, it also works for any $\mathbb{Z}_n$).

Answer (score 0):

Check it has no root. As in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, we have $x^3=x$ (this is *lil' Fermat*), it means $x^2+x-1$ has no root, you just have to set $x=1, -1,0$  successively.